# How to stop Coffeescript from escaping keywords?

Tags: coffeescript, escaping, keyword

I am trying to write a indexeddb function "delete".  It should read like this in JS:

```
var transaction = db.transaction('objectStore','readwrite');
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('objectStore');
objectStore.delete(id);
```

However, when I write it in CS:

```
transaction = db.transaction 'objectStore','readWrite'
objectStore = transaction.objectStore 'objectStore'
objectStore.delete(id)
```

Of course it outputs:

```
...
objectStore["delete"](id);
```

I didn't write a method for IDBTransaction called "delete", but I have to use it.  How can I keep CS from escaping the "delete" method and turning it into a "delete" key in an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks to pass through bare Javascript:

```
`objectStore.delete(id)`
```

will be compiled through verbatim. Try it here at my favorite site for interpreting between CS and JS: http://js2coffee.org/#coffee2js

```
transaction = db.transaction 'objectStore','readWrite'
objectStore = transaction.objectStore 'objectStore'
`objectStore.delete(id)`
```

becomes

```
var objectStore, transaction;

transaction = db.transaction('objectStore', 'readWrite');

objectStore = transaction.objectStore('objectStore');

objectStore.delete(id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you care that the JavaScript version is `objectStore["delete"](id)`? That's the same as `objectStore.delete(id)`.

For example, if you say this in CoffeeScript:

```
class B
    m: (x) -> console.log("B.m(#{x})")
class C extends B

c = new C
c.m('a')
c['m']('b')
```

The last two lines come out as this JavaScript:

```
c.m('a');
c['m']('b');
```

but they both call the same method.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XvNzB/

Similarly, if you say this in JavaScript:

```
var o = {
    m: function(x) { console.log('m', x) }
};
o.m('a');
o['m']('b');
```

The last two lines call the same method.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Y3eUW/

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't matter, but it was throwing a DOM error while the accepted answer did not.  Since I did not write the indexedDB spec, I am not sure why.

Comment: Perhaps we could tell you what's really going on if you could provide an example.

Comment: @MyTimeFinder I agree with mu, there's something else happening here.