# CoffeeScript + Node.js - "delete" function

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

I have a little problem with CoffeeScript. I'm trying to build a RESTful API in Node.js and Express. Here is the problematic part of the code:

```
express = require('express');
router = express.Router()
router.route '/todos/:todo_id'
.get (req, res) ->
    # do get ...
.delete (req, res) ->
    # do delete ...
.put (req, res) ->
    # do put ...
```

Which compiles to:

```
router.route('/todos/:todo_id')
.get(function(req, res) {
    # here's my get code
})["delete"](function(req, res) {
    # here's my delete code
}).put(function(req, res) {
    # here's my put code
});
```

The "delete" keyword seems to be tricky - when I replace it with any other word (get, put, delet, whatever), it compiles to `.keyword` just fine, but only "delete" keyword compiles to array-access-thing. I can't use any other keyword because of REST. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I might be in the few an far between but coffee script is the devil in disguise. You'll spend more time fixing compile errors than actual errors. Fact of the matter is, the `["delete"]` compilation is a quirk in Coffeescript. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024915/2068709

Comment: Well, it really works now, even with `["delete"]`, thank you. I agree, CoffeeScript isn't that great as it seems to be, but I really don't know anything better. Any ideas here? TypeScript maybe? Pure Javascript?

Comment: I pick pure javascript over other stuff any day. Yeah it might not look as pretty or might be longer, but you will have more control any day of the week.

Comment: TypeScript or Flow (from Facebook) over CoffeeScript, always.  Retaining the spirit of javascript/having the option to also just write plain javascript beats writing "something else" entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `delete` is a keyword, as you noticed yourself, you can't use it as the name of an identifier. But, since object properties in JavaScript can be accessed using `[]` as well, you can still define (and use) a method with the name of a keyword by using the bracket notation.

CoffeeScript knows that, and automatically compiles it correctly for you. This should have no impact on functionality.